# How to Convert Keras Datasets to Embedding Matrices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to use Keras's IMDB dataset.

This is how it looks like:

```
    An Input Vector Sample = [23022, 309, 6, 3, 1069, 209, 9, 2175, 30, 1, 169, 55, 14, 46, 82, 5869, 41, 393, 110, 138, 14, 5359, 58, 4477, 150, 8, 1, 5032, 5948, 482, 69, 5, 261, 12, 23022, 73935, 2003, 6, 73, 2436, 5, 632, 71, 6, 5359, 1, 25279, 5, 2004, 10471, 1, 5941, 1534, 34, 67, 64, 205, 140, 65, 1232, 63526, 21145, 1, 49265, 4, 1, 223, 901, 29, 3024, 69, 4, 1, 5863, 10, 694, 2, 65, 1534, 51, 10, 216, 1, 387, 8, 60, 3, 1472, 3724, 802, 5, 3521, 177, 1, 393, 10, 1238, 14030, 30, 309, 3, 353, 344, 2989, 143, 130, 5, 7804, 28, 4, 126, 5359, 1472, 2375, 5, 23022, 309, 10, 532, 12, 108, 1470, 4, 58, 556, 101, 12, 23022, 309, 6, 227, 4187, 48, 3, 2237, 12, 9, 215]

A Label Sample = 1
```

This is how I get it:

```
top_words = 5000
test_split = 0.30
from keras.datasets import imdb
(X, y), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data()  # num_words=top_words
```

The problem is in this way, I dont knwo what an input sentence is like?

How can I then put sum of pre-trained word vectors as the feature for that sentence?

Any way to do that beyond Keras too? Scikit learn also does not have the imdb dataset.

Thanks a lot for your help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset just stores the word indices as a sequence of integers as you discovered. Hidden in the `keras.datasets.imdb` [module](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/3eab6103e0069d261c3e3586c12d5aaf0a331429/keras/datasets/imdb.py#L105) is another function that *retrieves the dictionary mapping word indices back to words*; unfortunately it is not clearly documented. You can use that to convert indices back to words to find what the sentences look like.

There  is already a nice [blog post](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) on how to use pre-trained word vectors with the `Embedding` layer in Keras. You can load the vectors based on the dictionary mapping you get for IMDb dataset as the indices might not match.